# Question on submit and push buttons. and also the scripting language in HTML

Tags: html, browser

Iam working on HTML.and As for now Im going well.But the thing I want to know is about the submit button.I have created user and password and a submit button and a register button.The basic question on my mind for now is, how and where the user names and password are stored and how they are retrieved back to check if they exist or no ? Where do they save the user names and passwords?

and How do i save the user name and the password that is entered through submit button in some other file? I have written perl scripts and c programs for saving and retreiving passwords using file concepts.But how do i manage them in HTML.Do they also save these data in some file and search for the user and password using some python or perl script and send back the result?
because searching and sorting techniques are powerful with the above scripts.I dont know how to use them in HTML and also the question is,can we use them in HTML?

Please let me know How to make it through.And can we also redirect to some links when we use click button and push buttons ?

Comment: You seem to have several questions here, and most of them don't make a lot of sense. Focus on one problem, and describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to know Can we use scripting languages like perl in my HTML file if so how?

Comment: and also How the user names and passowrds are saved and retrieved and the last one is how i link to some url when i press click button . these are the questions i have in my mind . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we use scripting languages like perl in my HTML file if so how?

The `<script>` element lets you embed any langage you like in an HTML document for client side processing.

The languages supported by browsers are:

- JavaScript (universal among browsers that support scripting at all)
- VBScript (Internet Explorer only)
- PerlScript (Internet Explorer with a plugin that ActiveState used to distribute)
- Perhaps some others with support that is about as common as that of PerlScript

So, effectively, client side you can use JavaScript and only JavaScript.

Server side, you can use any language you like. The webserver just needs to be able to communicate (and, while inefficient, CGI just depends on STDIN/OUT and environment variables).

Comment: Gosh but how do i make use of them ? any small code? I mean where do i put that in my html code ?

Comment: Client side? `<script>` elements can go practically anywhere. Server side? Generally speaking, you should have a program that generates HTML using a template.